# Use STL std::sort the way as qsort_r

Tags: c++, c, sorting, stl

With [qsort_r](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html), we can use external parameters in the compare function. For instance,

```
int cmp_with_parameter(void *a, void *b, void *p) 
{
  return (int*)p[*(int*)a] - (int*)p[*(int*b)];
}

int main() {
  int values[] = {1,2,3,4};
  int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
  qsort_r(arr, 4, sizeof(arr[0]), cmp_with_parameter, values);
}
```

We can sort `int arr[]` by the value in `values[]`.

Now, I would like to implement the similar function with std::sort, that is how I can use external values in std::sort? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read up on functors and/or anonymous function objects (or "lambdas").

Comment: Load the parameters by reference or other convenience into a custom comparator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison function taken by `std::sort()` can be a function object holding suitable information. For example:

```
std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr),
          [=](int a, int b){ return values[a] < values[b]; });
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Maybe I should pass-by-reference in the lambada expression:)

Comment: @OphirGvirtzer: why? surely the array decays as usual and a pointer is captured. Given that arrays are non-copyable I can't see how it would work differently.

Comment: Yeah, we don't need reference when the array is a pointer. I have used vector<int> in another place. I am sorry for this. thanks:)

Comment: Dietmar - Yes, you're right. But the [=] syntax scares me. What if someones changes the array to be std::array or std::vector? Will he notice the problem and change the lambda capture? I would never use [=], instead I'd explicitly specify each variable I want to capture by value.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a *functor* as your comparator. A common way to make a *functor* is using a `struct` with the call operator overloaded:

```
struct cmp_with_parameter
{
    const int* values; // keep a pointer to the external array

    cmp_with_parameter(const int* values): values(values) {}

    // overloading this operator allows an object
    // of this struct to be called like a function.
    bool operator()(int a, int b) const
    {
        return values[a] < values[b];
    }
};

int main()
{
    int values[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    std::sort(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), cmp_with_parameter(values));

    // ...
}
```

If you compiler supports **C++11** you can simplify the `std::sort()` parameters:

```
int main()
{
    int values[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), cmp_with_parameter(values));

    // ...
}
```

Wikipedia has a good example of how to address this issue: **[Function Object:C/C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B)**

Comment: The way to figure out the end iterator can be dramatically improved, though: `std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), cmp_with_parameters(values))`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thanks, I was keeping it pre-C++11 but I'll add your suggestion as an useful note.

Comment: Well, C++11 is outdated with C++14 being the current standard. Why anybody would want to consider pre-C++11 is somewhat beyond me (although I realize that companies may have constraints on the version of C++ being used). ... and even with C++98 a simply `end()` function can determine the size of an array.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Its just that the question doesn't specify C++11 and I have seen quite a few askers say they are not able to use it. But I agree pre C++11 is getting pretty obsolete.